# cypress.origin throws error: (uncaught exception)Error: on only accepts instances of Function

Tags: javascript, cypress, uncaught-exception

I am using Cypress with Cucumber.

I am trying to test cross origin login but the origin method keeps on throwing error:

Code:

```
Given(/^the user login to the Test Page$/, function () {
  cy.visit("https://example-originalURL");
  cy.get("button").contains("Login").click();

  const credentials = {
    username: "hello",
    password: "user",
  };


  cy.origin("https://example-newURL", { args: credentials }, ({ username, password }) => {
    cy.get("#email", { timeout: 20000 }).type(username);
    cy.get("#password").type(password, { log: false });
    cy.get("button").contains("Login").click();
  });
});
```

Cypress.config.js

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: "t7unhv",
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("file:preprocessor", cucumber());
      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message +'\n\n');
          return null;
        },
      });
    },
    specPattern: "./cypress/e2e/features/*.feature",
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    defaultCommandTimeout: 15000,
    env: {
      devCentralUrl: "https://***.dev.***.com.au/login",
      testCentralUrl:
        "https://***.test.***.com.au/login",
      test***: "http://***.test.***.com.au",
      dev***: "http://***.dev.***.com.au",
      uat***: "https://***.uat.***.com.au",
      dataSource: "",
      environs: "test",
    },
    retries: {
      runMode: 0,
    },
    pageLoadTimeout: 15000,
    reporter: "mochawesome",
    reporterOptions: {
      reporterEnabled: "mochawesome",
      mochawesomeReporterOptions: {
        reportDir: "cypress/reports/mocha",
        quite: true,
        charts: true,
        overwrite: false,
        html: false,
        json: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Error:

```
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> on only accepts instances of Function

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.
```

I have tried multiple syntax changes like not passing the credentials as optional argument to cy.origin.
If someone can provide a quick help, that will be great.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is in the test code, it is likely to be that `newURL` is `undefined`. The error message suggests the problem is in the app, but that might be a red herring.

Try just adding a fixed string for the `cy.origin()` key,

```js
cy.origin('login', { args: credentials }, ({ username, password }) => {
  ...
})
```

Comment: for the sake of privacy, I have replaced the URL's with the variable name.
but in the actual code, I am using the actual URL

Comment: The error "on only accepts instances of Function" is referring to an event handler which will usually look like `on("event-name-here", () => {...})` but in this case the 2nd argument is missing. What does `cypressconfig.js` look like?

Comment: thanks, updated the config details in the original question.

Comment: Maybe it's `on("file:preprocessor", cucumber())` - does `console.log(typeof cucumber)` return `Function`? Most common pattern is that shown [here](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/HEAD/docs/quick-start.md) - presuming your preprocessor is the latest version.

Comment: I have updated the npm packages to the latest version. Also, I feel the preprocessor is fine because other feature files without the `cy.origin` is working fine.